# mvn integration test Could not initialize class com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCrypt

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, ssl, jpa

I have come across a strange issue whilst running a jenkins job.  The purpose of the jobs is to run a integration test.  the test works locally and everything is working fine.
I fire the test from jenkins using the following

```
-Dit.test=TestIT verify -Dspring.profiles.active=internal
```

I get the following error when i run this through jenkins. The jenkins job is using the same java version as the one i am running locally.

```
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
 javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
 org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC
 Connection     at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:279)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 67 more Caused by:
 org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
 instantiate [com.phoebussoftware.importcore.dao.NonWorkingDaysImpl]:
 Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
 javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
 org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC
 Connection     at
 org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:271)
    ... 80 more Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
 org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC
 Connection     at
 org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
    at
 org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at
 org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:492)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
 org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:372)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy125.getResultList(Unknown Source)    at
 com.phoebussoftware.importcore.dao.NonWorkingDaysDaoImpl.nonWorkingDays(NonWorkingDaysDaoImpl.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
 org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at
 org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy124.nonWorkingDays(Unknown Source)   at
 com.phoebussoftware.importcore.dao.NonWorkingDaysImpl.<init(NonWorkingDaysImpl.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
 Method)    at
 sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at
 sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
    ... 82 more Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException:
 Unable to acquire JDBC Connection  at
 org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
    at
 org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:90)
    at
 org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:112)
    at
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:47)
    at
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)
    at
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
    at
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
    at
 org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1929)
    at
 org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1898)
    at
 org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1876)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919)     at
 org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617)     at
 org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600)   at
 org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429)     at
 org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424)     at
 org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501)    at
 org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371)
    at
 org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1326)   at
 org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87)   at
 org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606)  at
 org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483)
    ... 102 more Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException:
 Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory ([TDS
 Driver]javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Algorithm missing:  )   at
 org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
    at
 org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
    at
 org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at
 org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:386)
    at
 org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:87)
    ... 123 more Caused by: com.inet.tds.Tds4SQLException: [TDS
 Driver]javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Algorithm missing:      at
 com.inet.tds.ab.a(Tds4Factory.java:134)    at
 com.inet.tds.ap.a(TdsConnection.java:3766)     at
 com.inet.tds.ap.a(TdsConnection.java:2088)     at
 com.inet.tds.ap.a(TdsConnection.java:2258)     at
 com.inet.tds.ap.<init(TdsConnection.java:192)  at
 com.inet.tds.z.<init(Tds4Connection.java:41)   at
 com.inet.tds.ab.a(Tds4Factory.java:38)     at
 com.inet.tds.TdsDriver.connect(TdsDriver.java:80)  at
 org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at
 org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at
 org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
    at
 org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
    ... 128 more Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Algorithm
 missing:       at
 sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.changeWriteCiphers(SSLSocketImpl.java:2142)
    at
 sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.sendChangeCipherSpec(Handshaker.java:1125)
    at
 sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.sendChangeCipherAndFinish(ClientHandshaker.java:1216)
    at
 sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(ClientHandshaker.java:1128)
    at
 sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:348)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026)    at
 sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:961)    at
 sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)     at
 sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:747)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
    at com.inet.tds.bf.a(TdsSocket.java:364)    at
 com.inet.tds.ap.a(TdsConnection.java:2085)     ... 137 more Caused by:
 java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Could not create cipher
 AES/128    at sun.security.ssl.CipherBox.<init(CipherBox.java:242)     at
 sun.security.ssl.CipherBox.newCipherBox(CipherBox.java:263)    at
 sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.newCipher(CipherSuite.java:519)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.newWriteCipher(Handshaker.java:832)
    at
 sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.changeWriteCiphers(SSLSocketImpl.java:2138)
    ... 149 more Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: No
 installed provider supports this key: javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:893)  at
 javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1396)     at
 sun.security.ssl.CipherBox.<init(CipherBox.java:237)   ... 153 more
 Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing
 implementation (algorithm: AES, provider: SunJCE, class:
 com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher$General)     at
 java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1617)     at
 javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:860)    ... 155 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
 com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCrypt   at
 com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.<init(AESCipher.java:185)    at
 com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher$General.<init(AESCipher.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
 Method)    at
 sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at
 sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1595)
    ... 156 more
```

Comment: The relevant part is `Could not create cipher AES/128` caused by TdsConnection.java.

Comment: So TdsConnection is part of the sql driver.  The setup is no different on my local  environment so i can't see why this is happening when i run through jenkins.

Comment: The error message is mostly related to old outdated JREs that don't support AES: Are you sure the correct JRE/JDK is installed and used?

Comment: So jenkins is currently setup to use the system jdk which is set to jdk 1.8.0_73.

Comment: installed latest jdk on the server and still the same issue.